# How to change backgroundColor of UIView with didSet on a property?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, enums, didset

I have a UIView with different states defined with an enum.
When I change the state, I would like to update its backgroundColor propertys. 
It doesn't work.

```
 enum State {
        case lock 
        case unlock
        case done
    }

    @IBDesignable
    class DeviceView: UIView {

        var state:State = .lock  {

            didSet(newValue) {

            print("PRINT didSet \(newValue)")

                switch newValue {
                case .unlock:
                self.backgroundColor = green   
                }
                self.setNeedsDisplay()     
        }
    }


    func initDevice(type:Type) {
        self.state = state
    }
```

In my view controller in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    device1View.initDevice(state: .lock)
    print("PRINT 1 \(device1View.state)")
}
```

Later in another place, I need to change the state of my DeviceView

```
print("PRINT 2 \(device1View.state)")
device1View.state = .unlock
print("PRINT new 3 \(device1View.state)")
```

The result:

```
PRINT didSet lock
PRINT 1 lock
PRINT 2 lock
PRINT didSet lock <--- ???
PRINT new 3 done
```

...and so on my backgroundColor is never updated.

I don't understand why the last didSet is "lock". It should be "unlock" no ?
I think it's the reason why my background color isn't updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass parameter to didSet . The state itself is already the new parameter in the didSet so you may change didSet code block with this;

```
didSet {

        print("PRINT didSet \(state)")

            switch state {
            case .unlock:
            self.backgroundColor = green   
            }
            self.setNeedsDisplay()     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DeviceView: UIView {
    var state:State?  {
        didSet(newValue) {
        print("PRINT didSet \(newValue)")
            switch newValue {
            case .unlock:
            self.backgroundColor = green   
            }
        self.setNeedsDisplay()     
}
```

Try like this.